# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new in Flutter. I face a problem about Flutter: Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1).

This is my Debug Console:

```
E/flutter ( 8328): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 8328): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
E/flutter ( 8328): ^
E/flutter ( 8328):
E/flutter ( 8328): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
E/flutter ( 8328): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1272:9)
E/flutter ( 8328): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:937:22)
E/flutter ( 8328): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter ( 8328): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
E/flutter ( 8328): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
E/flutter ( 8328): #6      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:155:10)
E/flutter ( 8328): #7      _UserCreateEnquiryScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:dragon_lyz_app/…/user/user_create_enquiry_screen.dart:112
E/flutter ( 8328): #8      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter ( 8328): #9      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 8328): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8328):
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: add your api response because its not convert your response into JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you fix it by not parsing an HTML text as JSON in your `build` method of the `_UserCreateEnquiryScreenState` class.

Since you posted no code and no other explanation, that is all the help we can give you.