# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) - Flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, api, dart, backend

I know there's another question related to this but badly ask.
([Flutter: Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70863095/flutter-unhandled-exception-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-characte)).

My debug console prints:
[image: 1]

When the button is pressed throws the exception:
[image: 2]

As you can see in the API, there's no response so there isn't communication between them both. I suppose is because of the exception.

With respect to the backend:

POST REQUEST:
[image: 3]

GET REQUEST:
[image: 4]

In this file I have the config of my frontend to connect with the backend:
[image: 5]

In case you wanna verify that my IP is correct:

Get this after running **ifconfig** in an Ubuntu OS:
[image: 6]

Really hope that anyone can help me out, thanks in advance !!

Comment: Post your api code snippet here

Comment: The API has lots of files

Answer (score -1):

So I see few things happening:

1. When you use Postman to send the get and post request, you are using localhost so you are able to call the api.
2. In your config file you are using a private ip (192.168.xx.xx), and this of course is because you can't use localhost on your emulator but I suppose the issue is because you don't have connection to that url.
3. You said before:

> there's no response so there isn't communication between them both. I
> suppose is because of the exception

but the truth is that the exception is the result of the lack of communication, not viceversa.
4. You can see that on flutter you are getting an html as the response not a json.

So in order to fix this you can do this:

1. Check that you are using the right ip and that you have communication.
2. Print the response body to get the full html response.